# Insert blank lines in a document before creating a table

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am creating a table in a word document - but want to add 2 blank lines before creating the table. The code below creates the blank lines but I need to move the cursor (clear the selection) before creating the table. The code currently creates the tables on top of the 2 new blank lines.

I'm sure I'm missing one simple line of code :). Thanks for your help!

```
With ActiveDocument.Sections(1)
    Selection.InsertParagraph
    Selection.InsertParagraph
End With


ActiveDocument.Tables.Add Range:=Selection.Range, NumRows:=1, NumColumns:=2
```

Answer (score 2):

**1. method:**

```
     Selection.TypeParagraph  
     Selection.TypeParagraph  
     ActiveDocument.Tables.Add Range:=Selection.Range, NumRows:=1, NumColumns:=2
```

**2. method:**

```
    Selection.InsertParagraph  
    Selection.InsertParagraph  
    Selection.EndKey Unit:=wdStory
    ActiveDocument.Tables.Add Range:=Selection.Range, NumRows:=1, NumColumns:=2
```